# file_get_contents() returns nothing

Tags: php, screen-scraping, file-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve data from the US National Archives' website using PHP's `file_get_contents()` function as I have in the past for making similar scripts. For some reason though, in this instance the function does not retrieve any of the file's content.

I must confess that I haven't much experience with this kind of work. Could someone indicate why the file might not be correctly returned, even though the file displays fine when I manually type the URL into the address bar. Here's the source code (or a minimal version which doesn't output anything):

```
   $asn = $_REQUEST['asn'];
$format = $_REQUEST['output'];
  $data = array();

if(!empty($asn))
{
    $url_to_get = 'http://aad.archives.gov/aad/print-record-detail.jsp?dt=893&mtch=1&tf=F&q=31371273&bc=sl,fd&rpp=10&pg=1&rid=2546302';
    $content = file_get_contents($url_to_get);
    echo $content;
}
```

And the URL we're trying to access is > http://aad.archives.gov/aad/print-record-detail.jsp?dt=893&mtch=1&tf=F&q=31371273&bc=sl,fd&rpp=10&pg=1&rid=2546302

Is it possible that running the script on `localhost` might be causing an issue here?

Comment: No. Trying to access the page using jQuery's `$.ajax()` returns an error, but the error text is empty.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled error reporting in PHP?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://aad.archives.gov/aad/print-record-detail.jsp?dt=893&mtch=1&tf=F&q=31371273&bc=sl,fd&rpp=10&pg=1&rid=2546302): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting

Comment: you may have `fopen_url_wrappers = Off` in your php.ini. Check the return value from `file_get_contents` as it can be `(bool)false` if it could not load the file/url or had a permissions issue. Displaying (or better yet, logging) errors and reviewing them will hint you as to what is failing.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, the redirection limit was reached?!

Comment: Just enable error_reporting as you should and find out for yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There will definitely be a warning in case of failure. That particular URL wants PHP to be configured with SSL support, because running on stock it gives me:

> failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

This tells me that I have to enable the `openssl` extension for PHP.